# File Server erlang response

Tags: concurrency, erlang, erlang-shell

I am trying to follow the very first example given in the Programming Erlang, Software for a concurrent world by Joe Armstrong. Here is the code:

```
-module(afile_server).
-export([start/1,loop/1]).

start(Dir) -> spawn(afile_server,loop,[Dir]).


loop(Dir) -> 

    receive
        {Client, list_dir} ->
            Client ! {self(), file:list_dir(Dir)};
        {Client, {get_file, File}} ->
            Full = filename:join(Dir,File),
            Client ! {self(), file:read_file(Full)}
    end,
    loop(Dir).
```

Then I run this in the shell:

```
c(afile_server).
FileServer = spawn(afile_server, start, ".").
FileServer ! {self(), list_dir}.
receive X -> X end.
```

In the book a list of the files is returned as expected however in my shell it looks as if the program has frozen. Nothing gets returned yet the program is still running. I'm not familiar at all with erlang however I can understand how this should work.

I'm running this in Windows 7 64-bit. The directory is not empty as it contains a bunch of other erlang files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So...  what `start/1` function is doing here? It's spawning a process which starts from `loop/1` and you don't just run it in your shell but spawning it too! So you have a chain of two spawned processes and process under `FileServer` dies imiedietly because its only job is to spawn actual file server which pid is unknown to you.

Just change line:

`FileServer = spawn(afile_server, start, ".").`

to:

`FileServer = afile_server:start(".").`

Comment: I had another look in the book. It seems I didn't read the line properly.

Comment: However why doesn't this work? I mean. Doesn't the PID point to this process?

Comment: @Bula PID points to process which spawned your file server. It's temporary and dies after spawning your server process which still exist but PID you have points to that temporary process. You can think of that as it's parent and file server is its child. You wanted PID of this child and not its parent. Your shell should be its parent but in your code it becomes its grandparent with unwanted process between them. Spawn means: create isolated process which starts executing function you passed and return its pid. Who is going to spawn afile_server:loop then? Proc you spawned in shell, not shell.

Answer (score 5):

The drawing below illustrates Lukasz explanation.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What tool did you use to draw the diagram ?

Comment: It is a plugin of Chrome: gliffy. I don't remember which drawing tool I used to add the shadows.